# Is there any way only paid user access the specific video via YOUTUBE.

Tags: video, youtube, dvd

I am planning to sell DVD via YOUTUBE, Is there any way only paid user access the specific video via YOUTUBE.

Comment: Don't big TV content providers get the ability to sell content on youtube? (unsure, didn't think ready this for an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an external process to manage it and then update either the privacy settings explicitly on youtube to add users names then you could update the list of valid users (and delete them if your business model requires it eg. unsubscribe), or add paid users to a "circle" and then restrict the video to be viewable only by people in the circle.